# Show that A is invertible

Tags: matrices

Suppose that A is an n by n Matrix and there exist matrix B such that BA=Identity. Show that A is invertible! 
My attempt is to use linear mapping associated with a matrix
L_A (x)=Ax and L_AB (x)=L_A L_B

Please help.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without invoking determinants, assume that there exists a **square** matrix $B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that $BA = I_n$. By considering the linear maps associated to $B,A$, we get $L_B \circ L_A = \operatorname{id}|_{\mathbb{F}^n}$. This implies that $L_A$ is one-to-one (for $L_A(\vec{x}) = \vec{0} \implies \vec{x} = L_B(L_A(\vec{x})) = L_B(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$) and then, by the rank-nullity theorem, $L_A$ is also onto. .

Comment: how do you know that L_B  is the inverse of L_A?

Comment: @dyyyyssss: Prove the following: If $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ and $g \colon Y \rightarrow X$ are functions, $f$ is one-to-one and onto and $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}|_{X}$ then $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}|_{Y}$.

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

$1=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det (B)\implies \det A\neq 0$

Answer (score -1):

Let $BA=I$. By multiplying from the right by elementary matrices I can always column reduce $A$ to, say, $A'$ and get $BA'=P$. $P$, as a product of elementary matrices is invertible and hence has no zero column. This implies that $BA'$ has no zero column, which implies that $A'$ has no zero column, hence $A'=I$. This means that $P$ is the right inverse of $A$, and $AP=I$. Finally, $B=BI=BAP=IP=P$ and hence $A$ is invetible.

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote?

Comment: yes:  Your answer suggests that any time you multiply a matrix $A$ on the right by one or more elementary matrices, to get some other matrix $A'$, then $A'=I$.  That is clearly not true so I felt no explanation was needed.  The reasoning "$A'$ has no zero column and hence $A'=I$" does not make sense.  Lots of non-identity matrices have no all-zero column.

Comment: I suppose your answer could be fixed if you assume you keep multiplying by elementary matrices to reduce $A$ to some special structure like "row echelon" (or perhaps "column echelon"?)  form and you assert something about the structure of that form.  You likely intended that, but it was not clear to me and the answer seemed to make strange claims.

Comment: @Michael Yes, of course, when I write to multiply by elementary matrices I mean to put in into "reduced column echelon form" It is an elementary exercise to prove that for a square matrix it is either an identity or has a column of zeros.